Deploying Azure App Service to Multiple Subscriptions in a Tenant using Terraform and Azure DevOps - Need Advice
I want to deploy and configure Azure App Service into 3 different subscriptions using Azure Terraform and Azure DevOps pipeline. Can I get some advice on how this can be done.
NOTE: For a single subscription I can make it work with out any issues.For multiple subscriptions I cannot do it.

I tried creating 3 different service connections

So far what I tried in VS code is:
app-deployment:
     vars.tf      - Contains all variables for all 3 different variables
     providers.tf - Contains all providers for all 3 different variables
     resources.tf - Contains terraform for creation of resource group, app service etc...
     main.yaml    - Pipeline to trigger init, validate, plan, apply

main.yaml:
trigger: none
pr: none

pool:
  vmImage: Ubuntu-latest

stages: 
- stage: deployAppService
  jobs:
  - job: to_Dev
    steps:
    - template: dev/deployTodev.yml
      parameters:
        serviceconnection: Azure-Deployment-dev
  - job: to_Acceptance
    steps:
    - template: acc/deployToacc.yml
      parameters:
        serviceconnection: Azure-Deployment-Acc
  - job: to_Production
  steps:
  - template: prod/deployToprod.yml
    parameters:
      serviceconnection: Azure-Deployment-prod

  

But I am facing issues with state files (.tfstate) as they are 3 different subscriptions.
Terraform workspaces
I also read about terraform workspaces but using Terraform with Azure DevOps pipelines I am having trouble configuring , can I please get some advice on how can I do this. Thanks

What does Contains all variables for all 3 different variables mean? This seems to be a copy/paste mistake. Do you mean you have all the variables for the 3 environments in the same file? You shouldn't mix environments. Take a look into the sample folder structure in Split applications into environment-specific subdirectories.

That is true. Yeah I did try to create 3 env_x.tfvars file.

Separate .tfvars per environment makes sense. I thought you were doing some else.

Have you tried of using subscription_id parameter under provider block. @Learning_Learning

In order to deploy terraform resources to two or more subscriptions, using multiple providers by passing alias parameter is an efficient way.
alias is used to pass the subscription name as shown below. Using that you can pass multiple subscriptions for deployment and reference it in the resource as azurerm.<aliasname>.
Refer blog by @Jeff Brown Tech for the relevant information.
Below is the complete code for your reference
provider "azurerm" {
  subscription_id = "f7bxxxxx014"
  tenant_id = "93xxxxf6d"
}
provider "azurerm" {
    alias = subscription2
    subscription_id = "subscription_id"
    tenant_id = "xxxx" //Provide tenant ID if the 2nd subscription existed in another tenant
}
provider "azurerm" {
    alias = subscription3
    subscription_id = "subscription_id"
    tenant_id = "xxxx" //Provide tenant ID if the 3rd subscription existed in another tenant
}


data "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
  name     = "Jahnavi"
}

resource "azurerm_app_service_plan" "example" {
  provider            = "azurerm"
  name                = "examplejahserviceplan"
  location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name

  sku {
    tier = "Standard"
    size = "S1"
  }
}

resource "azurerm_app_service" "example" {
  provider            = "azurerm"
  name                = "jahapservice"
  location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  app_service_plan_id = azurerm_app_service_plan.example.id

  site_config {
    dotnet_framework_version = "v4.0"
    scm_type                 = "LocalGit"
  }

  app_settings = {}
}
resource "azurerm_app_service_plan" "example" {
  provider            = "azurerm.subscription2"
  name                = "examplejahserviceplan"
  location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name

  sku {
    tier = "Standard"
    size = "S1"
  }
}

resource "azurerm_app_service" "example" {
  provider            = "azurerm.subscription2"
  name                = "jahapservice"
  location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  app_service_plan_id = azurerm_app_service_plan.example.id

  site_config {
    dotnet_framework_version = "v4.0"
    scm_type                 = "LocalGit"
  }

  app_settings = {}
}



@Jahnvi   Sorry, I am ware of this already. What I am trying to achieve is the same thing you did via Azure DevOps Pipeline. I did a up arrow for your time, thanks. Kind Regards

Ok. To achieve it with DevOps pipeline, you can inputs object with an inline script field by passing terraform commands.Have you tried that? @Learning_Learning

Have you tried it again! @Learning_Learning

yes it works now, thanks

@Learning_Learning, If this answer can work for you, you can accept it. This could be also helpful for other people who are looking for a solution of the similar questions.
